# How did Isaac Newton support himself in the period of self-study that he conducted at 23?(after he received his B.A.)

Tags: science, isaac-newton

I quote wiki :

> Soon after Newton had obtained his B.A. degree in August 1665, the
>   university temporarily closed as a precaution against the Great
>   Plague. Although he had been undistinguished as a Cambridge
>   student,[15] Newton's private studies at his home in Woolsthorpe over
>   the subsequent two years saw the development of his theories on
>   calculus,[16] optics, and the law of gravitation.

Comment: He was only 23 - perhaps he simply camped-in at his mother's.

Comment: Newton returned home to Lincolnshire during this period and was supported by his mother, Hannah Ayscough. When her second husband (the wealthy clergyman Reverend Barnabus Smith) died in 1653, she was was left with a good bit of wealth and property.

Answer (score 6):

These years are typically referred to Newton's "Golden years" due to the quantity and quality of his works during those years. Newton's Mother and Uncle managed the farm through out Newton's life. During the plague his family would have taken care of him, like provide him food clothing and shelter. His family knew that he was an "absent minded farmer" which is why his uncle initially sent him to Cambridge to study.

Comment: "Isaac Newton: Man Myth and Mathematics" by V. Frederick Rickey